# How much does water expand when heated, and does salt affect that?

Tags: water, solutions, heat

For this question, assume all things not mentioned are perfectly controlled, all at 14.7lbs of atmospheric pressure, and water is 100% pure of anything not mentioned, with no dissolved air.

Given a quantity of water that is 1 liter at 20°, what would the volume be when heated to 30°?

Secondly, the same question, except the water being heated is fully saturated with salt.

Comment: It would be useful if scientists would translate this data into something more meaningful to lay people.
For example, for 1 litre of sea water at the average salinity, the average global temperature and average air-pressure in millibars, what would be the volume be at increments of 0.5°. e.g. at what temperature would it be 1.1 litres?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The volumetric expansion of a liquid is given by the following equation
$$\Delta V=V_0\beta\Delta T$$
where $\beta$ is the coefficient of thermal expansion and $\Delta T$ is the change in temperature.

Here's [a link](http://publishing.cdlib.org/ucpressebooks/view?docId=kt167nb66r&chunk.id=d3_4_ch03&toc.id=ch03&brand=eschol%20) to a nice table containing coefficients of expansion for water, both pure and salinated.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride) shows the maximum solubility of salt in water to be around 36% (w/w).

From the first link we find that

for pure water at $25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$: $\beta = 257\times10^{-6}/\mathrm K$

for water with 35% $\ce{NaCl}$ dissolved at $25\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$: $\beta= 297\times10^{-6}/\mathrm K$

Now you should be able to calculate the values you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is very interesting. For whatever reason, this morning I came up with a theory that perhaps more of the see rise we are experiencing is due to expansion than is due to new water in the oceans. Immediately after asking this question, I Googled and found that this theory is nothing new, and that expansion might actually account for 70% of sea rise.

Answer (score 1):

For a starting point I would suggest http://web.mit.edu/seawater although this will not help much on the 'saturated' end of things since the salinity values in the tables do not reach the 20C saturation values. I leave finding the saturation value to the requester, since google brings it up quite easily.